# How can I change a text in a QML from another qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to change **myText.text** from the **main.qml** but **myText** is in an another folder. How can I do that?

**---main.qml---**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import "qrc:/secondfolder/pagetwo.qml" as PageTwo

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480
   title: qsTr("Hello World")

   Button {
       id: button
       x: 63
       y: 71
       width: 142
       height: 66
       text: qsTr("Button")

       MouseArea{
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked: {
               PageTwo.myText.text = "hello world"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**---pagetwo.qml---**

```
Item {
    Text {
        id: myText
        text: "default text"
    }  
}
```

When I run the code I got this error: `"qrc:/secondfolder/pagetwo.qml": no such directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your **PageTwo** in **main.qml** and give it id, like this:

```
PageTwo {
   id: pageTwo
}
```

Instend of `PageTwo.myText.text = "hello world"`  you need to write `pageTwo.myText.text = "hello world"`.

Then in **file PageTwo.qml** you have to write `property alias myText: myText`.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    PageTwo {
        id: pageTwo
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        width: 142
        height: 66
        text: qsTr("Button")

        onClicked: {
            pageTwo.myText.text = "hello world"
        }
    }
}
```

**PageTwo**

```
import QtQuick 2.14

Item {
    property alias myText: myText

    Text {
        id: myText
        text: "default text"
    }
}
```

I'd recomend you to read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html) and check some **qml example applications**.

Comment: In the Page Two the property should be:
property alias myText: myText.text